# Does an induced current depend on the material?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

In the textbook University Physics, when talking about induction experiments of coil, one of the points made is:

> If all these experiments are repeated with a coil that has the same shape
> but different material and different resistance, the current in each case is
> inversely proportional to the total circuit resistance. This shows that the
> induced EMFs that are causing the current do not depend on the material
> of the coil but only on its shape and the magnetic field.

I'm not sure I fully understand this. Isn't the resistance based on the resistivity of the material (therefore dependant on the material), length of the wire and cross-sectional area? Doesn't this mean that the material influences the resistance and therefore the induced current?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the induced *emf* is independent of the type of material used, but the induced current is dependent on the type of material used.

This is essentially from Faraday's Law: $$\varepsilon = -\frac{\text{d}\Phi_B}{\text{d}t} $$which shows that the induced emf is only depedent on the *magentic flux* linked through the loop, which implies that it depends on the magnetic field, the cross sectional area and the angle between $\vec B$ and $\vec A$.

For the induced current however:
$$I = \frac{|\varepsilon|}{R}$$ and as $R = \rho l/A$, the induced *current* is dependent on the material used , and is only inversely proportional to the total resistance of the circuit (the value of $\varepsilon$ won't change unless the previously mentioned parameters change.)

Hope this helps.